# Editing limits- disproportionate to impact of edit

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently came to edit a question, which required the adding of a couple of format tags as his original code couldn't be read, as the original code contained some SO-specific markup. But when I submitted the edit, it said that my edit must be 6 characters minimum. I feel that this limit is poor because the *quantity* of code and the clarity of the post can be massively affected by a pair of backticks in the right place or clicking the code button once- that is, the edit limit should take into account *modified* characters, even if those characters are indirectly modified by markup instead of changed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Covered here:

[Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites/77257#77257)

Is the post *so otherwise perfect* that nothing else in it can be improved? Really? If so then it is a rarified post indeed..